# Load a container

Tags: docker, containers

Hello I am new to docker. I have installed my base file which is Wordpress on My PC. Since i use multiple systems i copied my current commits from pc to opensuse. Now i want to load my committed file on to opensuse. Is there any possible way to do it. I tried doing run and i cannot see any changes???

Base file : Wordpress

```
docker run -dtip 192.168.56.10:80:80 -p 192.168.56.10:2222:22 -h baseWordpress --name baseWordpress--restart unless-stopped mine/wordpress /usr/bin/supervisor
docker start baseWordpress
```

Commit files

what should i use for commit file to run and start on opensuse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to have your own Dockerfile, where mine/wordpress is the based image, and you overwrite files with your commit files.

Or you could try to map a volume (-v option) in docker run command, and then copy your commit files to the mapped host folder. Next attach to the container, and move the files to correct location.